# What's the meaning of 'hit a lot of ground' in this tweet?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a tweet about using the illegal substances during pitching in the baseball game to improve the ball speed, movement, etc.

> Had a good chat with @notthefakeSVP about foreign substances. **We hit a
> lot of ground here**. For those who want to understand why pitchers use
> them, there's that. And plenty more about what this means for the
> sport, why it's a big deal and what the crackdown may mean for
> baseball.

I know the idiom 'hit the ground' which means 'drop down to the ground'. But it doesn't seem fit to this tweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the speaker used "hit a lot of ground" with the same meaning as "covered a lot of ground". My guess is that he meant that the discussion touched on many key aspects of the topic of the use of foreign substances in baseball.

People sometimes say that they "hit a lot of the main points" to say that they discussed many of the key aspects of a topic.

My guess is that the speaker combined "hit a lot of the main points" with "covered a lot of ground" to make a new idiom.

I'm sorry I can't do better than just hazard a guess right now. If someone has a good source for idioms, please share it here!